# What are vedantic teachings in Valmiki Ramayan?

Tags: ramayana, vedanta

I have read Avdhut Gita, Ashtavakra Gita and now wanted to rea Ramayan by Valmiki ji or Tulsidas Ji. But i am not sure which one to read. I want to know vedantic teachings imbibed in them and not just story only

Thanks

Comment: There is a commentary by Rāmānuja on Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa, I guess that might be interesting to check out in this regard. There is another commentary (called bhuṣaṇa) by Govindarāja who was a Śrī Vaiṣṇava. Another commentary is by Maheśvaratīrtha, who was disciple of Nārāyaṇatīrtha who wrote a commentary (called Laghuvyākhyā) on Siddhāntabindu of Madhusūdana Sarasvatī (a famed Advaitin).  I guess these commentators would offer Vedāntic viewpoints, if not others, we are still sure about Rāmānuja's commentary which would be from Vedāntic perspective.

Comment: thanks................

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Valmiki is the earlier. Tulsidasa's is of more recent vintage.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda yes resding valmiki ji. its very boring. i was looking stories like of jadbharat and ribhu nidagah story like that